# Is SQL Server Profiler causing massive SQL Server internal waits?

Tags: sql-server, wait, sql-server-profiler

I'm running SQL Server Profiler over a SQL Server 2008 SP3.
The server contains 30 DBs.
If I run SQL Server Profiler (columns EventClass, TextData, ApplicationName, 
NTUserName, LoginName, SPID, DatabaseName, HostName, ServerName, SessionLoginName) tracing 7 DBs (over 30) everything goes well.

If I trace 25 DBs (over 30), SQL Server starts to answer any request **50 times slower than normal**.
The strange thing (for me) is that checking machine CPU, Memory, Disk I/O and Network everything looks really fine.
Even SQL Event Monitor shows a low Processor Time, a low Waiting Tasks, a low Database I/O and a low Batch Requests/sec.

I guess the problem lies inside the SQL Server waits. What do you think?
Do you know if there is a specific parameter I can check to understand when SQL Profiler is slowing down my SQL Server?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Profile can have significant effects on the performances of your Instance yes. Extended Events is a far better tool, however, I can't remember how much use you can actually get out of that on 2008.

Comment: You are filtering the output aren't you?  How many rows per second does your trace return?

Comment: @Larnu: I'm going to check the Extended Events. Thanks.

Comment: @MJH: I guess it depends on working hours. I really do not know how to count rows per second in SQL Server Profiler, anyway there would be a strong difference between day and night.